# Explain C# Aggregate behavior

Tags: c#

I'm trying to learn C#, and use Aggregate.  I can use reduce no problem in Javascript, but for some reason I cannot get my code to operate.

My end goal is to take a List of chars (which are all numbers), convert them into numbers, Aggregate them, and return a value.  For now though, I just want to get Aggregate to work.

I set this before doing any aggregation: `int[] test = {1,2,3,4,5};`

When I have this code:

```
int result = test.Aggregate ((current, total) => {
    current += 1;
    current + total;
});
```

I am told: "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"
However I have seen examples of multi-line lambda functions.

I can remove the `current += 1;` line, and the curly braces and it will work, but my goal is to run several things before each aggregation.

How do I have a lambda expression execute multiple lines of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`current + total` is not valid C# in that context. It's only valid in the shorthand form for single line lambdas with no curly braces. Otherwise you need an explicit `return` statement.

You need to rephrase it as `return current + total;`

When you use it without the curly braces, the `return` is implicit.

Comment: I am a fool.  Ok, so adding the return works.  Can you explain why when the lambda is wrapped in {} I need to have a return.  But when it's one-lined having a return is invalid?

Comment: It's just a compiler feature that in the single-line version without braces, a shorthand form without the return statement is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Lambdas that return a value and use curly braces require a 'return' statement:

```
int[] test = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

            int result = test.Aggregate((current, total) =>
            {
                current += 1;
                current += total;

                return current;
            });
```